# Hierarchy level with many dimension attributes in Analysis Services

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, hierarchy

I would like to define a `Company - Product - Edition` hierarchy similar to:

```
All
 |--Microsoft / Redmond / MSFT
 |   |--Windows
 |   |   |--Windows 7
 |   |   |--Windows Vista
 |   |   
 |   |--Office
 |   |   |--Office 2010
 |   |   
 |--Oracle / Santa Clara / ORCL
     |--Java
     |   |--Java 7
     |   
     |--MySQL
         |--MySQL Standard Edition
```

I would like the `Company` level to consist of many attributes, for example: name (let's call it *primary attribute*) as well as headquarters and NYSE code (*secondary attributes*). I don't want to concatenate them into a single value; the users should be able to place the *secondary attributes* in the report when they need them.

Is it possible in SSAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not in the way you're thinking.   You can't add additional attributes to the levels of a hierarchy, but you can add those attributes to the dimension and relate them to the attributes that are in a hierarchy, using the "Attribute Relationships" tab.  You won't be able to refer to the "secondary attributes" through the hierarchy, though.  You'll refer to them directly in the dimension.